# Invalid parameter combnation AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble debugging an error I am getting.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: Network interfaces and an instance-level subnet ID may not be specified on the same request
```

This is the code.

```
    # Make EC2s with AWS Ubuntu 20
    instances = subnet.create_instances(ImageId='ami-0885b1f6bd170450c',
                                        InstanceType='m1.small',
                                        MaxCount=num,
                                        MinCount=num,
                                        Monitoring={'Enabled': True},
                                        KeyName=key_name,
                                        IamInstanceProfile={
                                            'Arn': 'arn goes here',
                                        },
                                        NetworkInterfaces=[{
                                            'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                            'SubnetId': subnet.subnet_id,
                                            'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                            'Groups': [security_group.group_id]
                                        }])
```

What is baffling me is that I do not specify a top level subnet id. And even when I remove subnet id entirely I get the error.

My guess is that something is being default set but I do not know how to stop that if it is the case.

Comment: Boto3 has a Subnet object - it appears he's calling this method: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Subnet.create_instances

My first thought was that by using subnet.create_instances, the subnet was being inadvertently specified twice, but weirdly the documentation seems to imply that not specifying it would use the default VPC & Subnet despite the fact that the creation call is performed via a specific Subnet object. Maybe try leaving off DeviceIndex?

Comment: Did not work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subnet` is probably an instance of [Subnet](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#subnet) class from `boto3`. Thus by using this you are **implicitly setting instance level subnet**, resulting in your error.

Thus, I think you should consider using [create_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) from `boto3.resource('ec2')` instead of your `subnet.create_instances` if you want to manipulate network interfaces:

```
ec2 = session.resource('ec2') # or boto3.resource('ec2')

instances = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-0885b1f6bd170450c',
    InstanceType='m1.small',
    MaxCount=num,
    MinCount=num,
    Monitoring={'Enabled': True},
    KeyName=key_name,
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'arn goes here',
    },
    NetworkInterfaces=[{
        'DeviceIndex': 0,
        'SubnetId': subnet.subnet_id,
        'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
        'Groups': [security_group.group_id]
    }])

print(instances)
```

Comment: @Keiros No problem. Little edited the question to fix indentation.